# Should I use "each" here or "every"?

Tags: word-choice

He was stationed as a guard at northern city-gates. There were fifty guards totally, at each city-gate, appointed to protect the gate from robbers, marauders and thieves. There were two junior commanders at _____ gate, each of them commanding twenty-five guards.

Should I use *each* in the blank space or *every*? Personally, I would like to use "every", since "each" is already being used several times. Would the sentence be grammatically correct and appropriate if I use "every"?

Comment: You may use either one. But make it "fifty guards total".

Comment: I'd make it 'There were fifty guards in total at each city gate, ...'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both. It changes the emphasis a little as [this Cambridge blog shows](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/each-or-every).

> We use each to refer to individual things in a group or a list of two or more things. It is often similar in meaning to every, but we use every to refer to a group or list of three or more things.

Since there are just two gates, I'd suggest each.

Comment: The question is not totally clear, but I can't deduce that there were just 2 gates.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth if there are two officers covering each gate with twenty five guards each and there are fifty guards total my mathematics come up with two gates total.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth strike that, there are fifty guards at each gate. You're right, there is no indication that there are only two gates.

Comment: I'll leave the striking to you. But the each vs every debate has been covered in a previous question.

Comment: In fact there are 8 gates in total. Fifty guards are stationed at _each_ gate and there is a junior commander above _every_ twenty-five of them (guards).

Answer (score 2):

I would use every there. Your sentence structure would put "each gate, each of them" which is slightly repetitive.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. I am wondering if using "every" here would be grammatically and aesthetically a put off.